# How to find a family of ellipses which is left unvaried by a given linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $$T = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \ .$$
Find a family of ellipses which are left unvaried by the transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $T$ doesn't have finite order. Let $P \in \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ be a point in the plane, different from the origin. Consider the sequence $P, TP, T^2P, \dots$. Describe the topological closure of its image.

Comment: I assume you are not looking for an invariant family of ellipses, but rather for a family of invariant ellipse.

Comment: Note that $T$ is conjugate to $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac14&\frac{\sqrt{15}}4\\-\frac{\sqrt{15}}4&\frac14\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So, if $R$ is the matrix you introduced and $T=Q^{-1}RQ$ for some invertible $Q$, then maybe if one can find an ellipse $\mathcal{E}$ such that $Q\mathcal{E}$ is a circle, then $T\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{E}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(also to @Hagen von Heitzen)

Edit : I have completely reorganized my answer.

Let us call $q$ the quadratic form that is left invariant by matrix $P$, i.e.,

$$q(x,y)=x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}xy+y^2$$

Why is it invariant ? Because it is preserved by operation $P_{n+1}=TP_n$.

Indeed, with coordinates (a similar argument could be given using matrices) :

$$\begin{cases}x_{n+1}&=&\dfrac{x_n}{2}-y_n\\y_{n+1}&=&x_{n}\end{cases}$$

one obtains this identity:

$$x_{n+1}^2-\dfrac{1}{2}x_{n+1}y_{n+1}+y_{n+1}^2 \ \ = \ \ x_n^2-\dfrac{1}{2}x_ny_n+y_n^2$$

as can be checked by expanding the LHS of :

$$\left(\dfrac{x_n}{2}-y_n\right)^2-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x_n}{2}-y_n\right)x_{n+1}+x_n^2 \ \ = \ \ x_n^2-\dfrac{1}{2}x_ny_n+y_n^2$$

Thus, given the initial point $P_0(x_0,y_0)$, the set of points $P_n$ belongs to the ellipse with equation:

$$x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}xy+y^2=k \ \ \text{with} \ \ k=x_0^2-\dfrac{1}{2}x_0y_0+y_0^2$$

(This ellipse could be interpreted as "iso-energetic').

Why are these points **densely** scattered on this ellipse, as can be inferred intuitively by looking at the example of the green points on the figure below ? It remains to be proved.

Concerning the family of ellipses, let us call $(E_n)$ the image of the unit circle by $T^n$ ($n \geq 0$ or $n < 0$). $(E_n)$ is an ellipse, as the image of an ellipse by an affine transform remains an ellipse. The set of all curves $(E_n)$ constitutes the looked for family. One can see below an image of this family limited to range $0 \leq n \leq 40$ (note that the unit circle is one of these curves).

The topological closure of this image **seems to be** the set $(S)$ of all points situated between 2 ellipses, but I have no proof for that. I conjecture that these ellipses are with equation $x^2+y^2-\frac{1}{2}xy=k^2$ for values of $k$ that could be $3/4$ and $5/4$.

[image]

Comment: I think that would be an unvariant family of ellipses, and not a family of unvariant ellipses, as Hagen von Eitzen pointed out? To be honest I don't know explicitly which of the two my question required, as it is taken from an online PDF.

Comment: I tend, of course, to privilegize my solution... because, in particular, it looks consistant in view of the second part (the union of sets $(E_n)$ constitutes a dense set). Could you indicate in which "pdf" document you have found this question ? It could help...

Comment: It's from an entrance examination for a master's degree in an italian school (SISSA). I translated it word for word though.

Comment: I have completely reorganized my answer placing in evidence the associated invariant quadratic form.